# ArcMap labels that come from different fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, if-else

I am trying to make labels for a feature class called m_GraveLotSingle. I have a field that is called "Raised_Flat". If the field is "RAISED" I would like it to show the label of another field called "Grave_Posi". If the field is "FLAT" I would like it to show the "Lot_1" field.

Is this possible?

Comment: I think you should look into Label Expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create two different label classes (changing labeling method in the layer's properties dialog) and based those two clases on SQL queries.

One class with the statement
`Raised_Flat= 'RAISED'` in wich the label field would be [Grave_Posi]
The other with `Raised_Flat= 'Flat'` and the label field [Lot_1]

You can look at this for a more detailed explanation: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/displaying-labels-using-label-classes-to-label-fea.htm

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation helped, I had been looking at the arcgis explanation and just couldn't make it work. Also I had the default still on so kept having double labels...  Thanks again!